# Formula to get percentage from a target, start, and current numbers

Tags: percentages

I have 3 numbers:

- start = 0;
- current = 4;
- target = 10;

I want to figure out how far along `current` is in the percentage from `start` too `target`;

So in this example the percent would be 40%.

How would I figure out this if `start` were `2`? I'm struggling to wrap my head around the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{part}}{\text{whole}}=\frac{\%}{100}$$

e.g

1. What is $45\%$ of $500$?

Answer:$=500\times\frac{45}{100}=225$

2. What is $20\%$ of $50\%$ of $60\%$ of $200$?

Answer: $(((200\times \frac{60}{100})\times \frac{50}{100}))\times \frac{20}{100}=12$

---

In your example: if `start` was  equal $2$ so it is $50\%$ from the `current`$=4$ and it is $20\%$ from the `target`$=10$

Answer (score 3):

To find the percentage, compute
$$
\frac{\text{current progress}}{\text{total interval}} = \frac{current - start}{total - start}
$$
then convert this fraction/decimal to a percentage.